# Vary number of votes based upon how many threads you've read

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

I had a suggestion about the number of votes a user is allotted per day.  Most of the time, 30 is plenty, but there have been occasions where I've gone through a lot of threads and run out rather quickly.

I wonder if there is some way to tie the number of votes to the number of threads that you've read (defining "read" by using some yet to be determined mechanism).

Just a thought...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't make sense in my opinion: My straightforward method of abuse would be to open a few hundred threads in different tabs and wait the required time.

Comment: Could you think of another mechanism to thwart such abuse?  Also, I would think that would take a lot of work to open up all of those tabs unless you used some type of script.

Comment: @jonsca: I have no idea how to test if someone read something, definitely not. I guess I could make a lot of money if I had. (And even without a script there's no problem to open 100 tabs in about a minute - use middle mouse click.)

Comment: I've decided to redact my specification for the mechanism by which the system would accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting votes/day is also a way to keep people from becoming too wrapped up in StackExchange.  Voting well takes time [(trust me, I know!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130540/ward) unless you blindly click and vote up.  Running out of votes is a good sign that you've read enough questions for one day.